# How to get the system icon for any file/folder

Tags: c#

How can I retrieve the system icon associated with a file/folder so that
I can show it in the list view adjacent to the file/folder name?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon`

```
 Icon icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(filepath);
```

Take a look at [Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.extractassociatedicon.aspx) documentation

Note: this works only for files. For folders you need P/Invoke <del>[sample is here](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/icons/article.php/c4261/Getting-Associated-Icons-Using-C.htm)</del> **Edit:** Page is now defunct, please refer to [this copy on the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20130814062331/http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/icons/article.php/c4261/Getting-Associated-Icons-Using-C.htm).

Comment: this only for file

Comment: It doesn't work for folder, as I tested.

Answer (score 0):

See *[Obtaining (and managing) file and folder icons using SHGetFileInfo in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2532/Obtaining-and-managing-file-and-folder-icons-using)*.